# Twitter Ruby API: How do I unfollow a person?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, twitter-gem

I wanted to know if there is any method known as Twitter::unfollow to unfollow a person using Twitter Ruby API.

I have read the documentation provided on Github but it doesn't seem to help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not in the documentation, an examination of the source shows that you can do

```
@client.unfollow('stephenfry')
```